# display additional information in internet explorer f12

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

There is one web page that someone wrote at my company. It has been working great. Anyway, since no one has touched for ages. The page only works on Internet explorer. That is the reason I am working on it to upgrade and do improvement. Yes, I have source code, but I don't know if the source code is up to date.

That is the history.

The page is written in ASP.net. Actually my question has something to do with HTMl and CSS
There are some enhancement I have to do for certain pages. For the pages I am not doing enhancement, I have to make sure the cosmetic and business work same as the existing ones.

Since existing one on the production only works on IE (version 10 compatible view). Anytime, the source code does not produce the exact result as the one on the production. I used the f12 tool to find out the CSS information. It tells me the inline information. I can also trace the external CSS class info. However, compare with Chrome and Firefox firebug, I realize there is lots information missing. in F12. In Firebug, I can trace back where all the styles and inherited properties. It does not matter whether the properties are set in the existing pages. Therefore, I can find some "hidden" properties in Firebug or Chrome tool.

Anyway, I can get more detail information in F12 tool

[image: This is F12 style window. Not lots information in the window]

[image: This is F12 Trace window. There is not much information also.]

[image: Chrome does have more information]

I am not going to upload the element window in Chrome. There is too much information.

Can I get detail information in F12?

Any other trick I can inspect the element

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

F12 will show different elements depending on the browser you are using, when you press F12 on a page you are looking at what the browser uses to render a page, Furthermore if the page is built in .asp there are a lot of extra code that gets inherited from asp tags. This makes things very messy if you are trying to copy code from inspect element.

Comment: I am asking if  Internet Explorer F12 tool can display more information. F12 in Chrome and Firefox do display additional information. They are messy, but it does help me to troubleshoot the style. It is impossible to copy codes. My goal is referencing the style and make adjustment.

Comment: It depends on the version of IE you are using. If you are using IE10 or below the answer is no. But if you are using IE edge the answer is yes.

Comment: like I said, the existing page only works on IE 10 compatible view. I guess the only solution is try to figure out myself. That is the reason I don't use IE. If it weren't for this reason, I wouldn't use IE. Chrome and Firefox are better tools to inspect the elements. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you send a link to the page?

Comment: Even many people lots users are using the production, I don't know if I can disclose that. For development, definitely, it is locked within our environment. Thank you for your help

Comment: Well you can still try to open it in IE edge in compatibility view.